# Javascript access CSS engine

Tags: javascript

Im building Javascript games(2D). The hardest part is creating a colission Detection.
Yesterday a Idea came to my mind and I want to ask if its possible. In CSS you have got the z-Index property. If an Objecte is at the same position as another and has a lower z-index its coverd by the other. If I set all collission objects to z-index 0 and my Player to 1 my Player would cover the objects when colliding. Can i acces the CSS engine to use the overlapping? If its possible i could set some kind of callback to detect colission and dont lose Performance.

Thanka for your Held
Miemels

Comment: This is not possible. The CSS object model is pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a canvas, i would use javascript variables and keydown functions. You can draw an image using the basic

```
ctx.drawImage('replace with image src', 'img x axis', 'img y axis').
```

and when the user uses a key down function the x axis moves, and all you need to do is call the function again for the image to move. w3 school and youtube videos have tons of canvas tutorials. You can make two images, and make a function that checks if they are a certain amount of pixels away. Please reply with any questions!